# Samba (на Astra Linux 1.6) и клиент на Win странно дружат

Tags: windows, samba, astra-linux

С помощью samba на астре развернут файловый сервер, который по сути просто директория с общим доступом. Есть четыре клиента на astra linux 1.6 и один на win 7. Линуксовые клиенты функционируют нормально, подрубаясь по логину и паролю, которые внесены в список клиентов самбы на сервере (под каждого создан пользователь). Виндовый же не может использовать ни одну из этих пар логинов и паролей (просто неудачная авторизация), работает только связка логин+пароль от админского пользователя машины с файловым сервером, что как-то ненормально... Есть какое-то решение этой проблемы? Почему только админ? Создавались все одинаково.

Логи:

```
В log/messages:

Aug 26 18:09:11 DcmsFS smbd_audit: nobody|192.168.73.59|IPC_|connect|ok|IPC$

В log/samba:
2020/08/26 18:09:11.488002,  1] ../lib/param/loadparm.c:1823(lpcfg_do_global_parameter)
  WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
[2020/08/26 18:09:11.555555,  1] ../lib/param/loadparm.c:1823(lpcfg_do_global_parameter)
  WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
[2020/08/26 18:09:26.847364,  1] ../lib/param/loadparm.c:1823(lpcfg_do_global_parameter)
  WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
[2020/08/26 18:09:26.862028,  1] ../lib/param/loadparm.c:1823(lpcfg_do_global_parameter)
  WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
[2020/08/26 18:09:26.873754,  1] ../lib/param/loadparm.c:1823(lpcfg_do_global_parameter)
  WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
```

На всякий еще smb.conf

```
[global]
workgroup = 01050-1
netbios name = dcms_share
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 1000
map to guest = Bad User
security = user
server role = standalone server
log level = 1 vfs:1
full_audit:prefix = %u|%I|%S
full_audit:success = connect, open, mkdir, rmdir, unlink, write, rename
full_audit:failure = connect, open, mkdir, rmdir, unlink, write, rename
full_audit:facility = local5
full_audit:priority = notice
vfs objects = full_audit
 
[fs_share]
comment = public
path = /home/fs_share
#create mask = 0777
force create mode = 0777
available = yes
public = yes
writable = yes
browseable = yes
directory mask = 0777
```

Comment: Стандартный вопрос: что в логах? (добавьте в вопрос)

Comment: они не очень содержательны, добавила

Comment: попробуй вводить с доменом (имя машины сервера)

Comment: Судя по логам - оно подключается как nobody... Если его включить - работает?

Comment: С доменом при подключении на клиенте пробовала вводить - то же самое.

Comment: @Sheridan в том и дело, в логах connect ok, а по факту не могу получить доступ. Кого включить? Не очень понятно

Comment: Кстати, а в journalctl ничего интересного не видно?

Comment: в journalctl нет записей по подключению (они там все в 16:50 заканчиваются, а подключение после 18 было)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавила в smb.conf в секцию global эти строчки:

```
passdb backend = tdbsam
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %U
```

и все заработало. Видимо проблема была в хранении информации о пользователе (первая строчка указывает, что информация об учетных записях пользователей будет храниться в базе данных tdbsam).

UPD:
Все таки это не решение. А окончательно помогло на Win клиенте:
Пуск - Панель управления - Администрирование - Локальная политика безопасности - Локальные политики - Параметры безопасности
Сетевая безопасность: минимальная сеансовая безопасность для клиентов на базе NTLM SSP - убрать галочку с "Требовать 128-битное шифрование". Таких параметра два - выполнить для обоих
Сетевая безопасность: уровень проверки подлинности LAN Manager - выбрать в списке пункт "Отправлять LM- и NTML-ответы

И добавить в smb.conf на сервере:

```
ntlm auth = yes
client ntlmv2 auth = no
```